# Coffeescript - how do I check string equality when passing string through a splat?

Tags: string, coffeescript, comparison, splat

I'm having trouble checking whether two strings are equal when one of them was passed through a splat argument. Because coffeescript uses strict comparisons, and because it makes a copy of the arguments when they go through a splat, I can't get the strings to compare properly without resorting to backticks.  Is there a better way?  Here's a minimal piece of code that demonstrates the problem:

```
check=(arg) ->
  if arg == 'foo' then "'#{arg}'=='foo'" else "'#{arg}'!='foo'"

emit=(args...) ->
  check(args)

console.log(emit('foo'))
console.log(check('foo'))
```

The output from this will be as follows:

```
> coffee mincase.coffee
'foo'!='foo'
'foo'=='foo'
```

EDIT:
 mu is too short gave me the key, so the revised working code looks like this (everything is the same except emit)

```
emit=(args...)->
  check.apply(null,args)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use a splat, the splat puts the splatted arguments into an array. For example:

```
f = (x...) -> console.log(x instanceof Array)
f(6)
```

will give you a `true` in the console. The [fine manual](http://coffeescript.org/#splats) isn't so fine in this case, it doesn't exactly spell it out, it assumes that you understand how JavaScript's [`arguments`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope/arguments) object works and leaves out the explicit *splat puts your arguments into an array* part.

So you end up passing an array to `check` and an array compared with a string using CoffeeScript's `==` (or JavaScript's `===`) will never be true.

If you want `emit` to check the first argument, then you need to say so:

```
emit = (args...) -> check(args[0])
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/TBndM/

Comment: Thanks! I've edited the question a bit to indicate more details about what I'm actually up to, but this solved the problem. Instead of getting args[0] I'm now doing check.apply(null,args) so that I can pass through multiple arguments (this wouldn't have been clear from the code I posted though).

Comment: @Erik: You can also splat in a function call (`f(array...)`) if you don't want to explicitly `apply`, for example: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/Gjh7G/

Comment: Cool, that is much nicer. Thanks again